# How to make PHP warnings fail PHPUnit test cases?

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am running continuous integration for a PHP project with Jenkins, Ant and PHPUnit 4.5.0. Jenkins's xUnit plugin will process the XML logs produced by PHPUnit.

Some significant errors (for example, referring to a file that is not pushed to VCS) only raise a PHP warning in PHPUnit, and warnings are not included in the log. Therefore the build is marked as successful even though it needs fixing.

How could I make the PHP warnings fail the build, for example by raising an exception for a test that produces warnings?

Answer (score 7):

We have to add `failOnWarning="true"` to treat such warnings as errors:

```
There was 1 warning:
1) The data provider specified for Tests\CreateSomethingTest::testCreateSomething is invalid.
FAILURES!
Tests: 841, Assertions: 2493, Failures: 1, Errors: 0.
```

So our config looks like:

```
<phpunit 
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         failOnWarning="true">
```

Comment: For anyone else wondering, `convertWarningsToExceptions` refers to PHP warnings (emitted with something like `trigger_error('warning', E_USER_WARNING);`) and `failOnWarning` refers to PHPUnit warnings. There's also `failOnRisky`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that options `convert...ToExceptions` are set to `true`. Unfortunately [options are not available in command-line](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html), so you have to create `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true">
</phpunit>
```